# Import into Marketing Cloud All Subscriber List from a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud

is there a limit on the number of records that can be imported in the all subscriber list via an import? I am trying to troubleshoot an issue with an import to the all subscribers where more than 100k records have been updated in Salesforce CRM. Assuming that the connector would be able to sync all data in before the automation starts, adds them to a data extension, a file extracts them to SFTP and brings them into the all subscribers list via an import.

Comment: In my past experience, I have imported upto 6 million subscribers using file transfer and import activity. hence it is hard to give a discrete answer and I guess as long as the file transfer can transfer the file into sftp and back into all subscribers via import, there shouldn't be any issues. Do you know what issue have you faced? Or are you just preparing for edge cases?

Comment: @BradSapkota preparing from edge cases -  I believe data migrated record bulk edited 100k + records in SFDC and did not sync in time. My automation then looked for discrepancy between the All Subscriber list and Master table in the past hour based on the last modified date and record were missed. I believe because did not sync in time and as the automation runs every hour when it run again was too late to include them

Comment: You can also export them directly from Salesforce via CSV and then import directly in All subscribers. However I think that MC connector should Sync 100K records in 1 hour (30records/Sec).
In Marketing Cloud under "Configure Synchronization" of Contact Object SYNC the option "Poll Schedule" is setted up to 15/30 minutes or 1 hour?